# The POM for <name> is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available

Tags: java, maven

**This question is outdated and no longer relevant. I have since moved to Gradle for my project build and can no longer verify that answers do or do not work.**

I've run into a few issues with Maven. Let me first describe my project setup:

```
Framework
|  -- Apache Commons Math 3.0
|  -- Bouncy Castle 1.5
|  -- etc.. (lots more)
|________
|        Client
|        | -- GUI libraries
|        | -- etc.
|
|________
         Server
         | -- Server Libraries
         | -- etc.
```

So essentially I have a framework that contains most dependancies and then two projects, "Server" and "Client" that contain their own BUT also the framework as a dependancy (being a module of Framework.). I installed the Framework project into my local repository and both my projects can see the Framework-Native code (aka my own logic). HOWEVER they don't seem to be able to use any of the dependancies of the Framework Project. When trying to build either of the "child"-projects I get this:

```
Invalid POM for de.r2soft.empires.framework:Framework:jar:Alpha-1.2, 
transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, 
enable debug logging for more details
```

I've tried to find the reason behind this (or better yet a solution) but haven't found anything that fixed my issues. Hope someone here can help. My maven version seems to be 3.2.1 (that's what -version tells me anyways)

Here are my framework-pom.xml and the client-pom.xml on pastebin:

Framework: http://pastebin.com/cceZECaT

Client: http://pastebin.com/1Cuxve5F

Help is appreciated.

Comment: As far as I remember *Invalid POM for de.r2soft.empires.framework:Framework:jar:Alpha-1.2, 
transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, 
enable debug logging for more details* is a WARN message, so try following what is suggested and run the maven phase in debug mode to have relevant information. This can be done with `-X` option.

Comment: Well...I ran it with --debug on, yes. Wrote the output to a textfile. Check it out on pastebin here: http://pastebin.com/GZdMfWnj From what I can tell it's nagging about the jar I added manually? But if not like that...how am I supposed to add it? :/ (So that my colleagues can use it as well and not have to go to console and install 100 things)?

Comment: @AreusAstarte did you find a solution for this? I an facing the same problem. I am having a dependency defined as system scope.

Answer (score 57):

One reason for this is when you rely on a project for which the parent pom is outdated. This often happens if you are updating the parent pom without installing/deploying it.

To see if this is the case, just run with `mvn dependency:tree -X` and search for the exact error. It will mention it misses things you know are in the parent pom, not in the artifact you depend on (e.g. a jar version).

The fix is pretty simple: install the parent pom using `mvn install -N` and re-try

Comment: Thank you so much for this, I was pulling my hair out trying to get this to work and this solved it!

Comment: True, mine is the same even I built the module individually and by the order, the parent pom must be built first.

Comment: What -N switch do?

Comment: -N will build a project WITHOUT building it's sub-modules. So in the case of "mvn install -N", you will install the parent pom without trying to build it's children too (thus avoiding a circular dependency)

Comment: SOLUTION (For me): `mvn dependency:tree -X` output included WARNINGs like the original question, but also FATALs like: `[FATAL] Non-readable POM 
/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/toolchain/jetty-toolchain/1.7/jetty-toolchain-1.7.pom: input contained no data @ <full-path-to-same-pom-file>`.  

So I `rm -rf ~/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty` then `mvn clean compile` ...which re-downloaded the need files -- and it's been fine ever since.

Answer (score 24):

I had a similar error,
In my case remove all related artifacts from the local repository was the workaround...

Comment: similar issue. had to clear my .m2/repository to get it to work.

Comment: Thank! I had similar error and removing the related artifacts in my .m2/repository resolved the problem...

Answer (score 10):

Remove repository folder inside .m2 and launch mvn clean install.

Keep us informed by the result and Good luck

Comment: This did it for me. Sometimes apparently there will be corrupted files when they download to the local .m2 repo

Comment: This did not solve the issue for me. I had to restore my .m2 folder.

Answer (score 4):

I have the same kind of issue and I may have the answer.
I have a top level project `MyProject` and `Module1` and `Module2`.
`Module2` depends on `Module1` and the entry is listed as a (default) dependency.
MyProject

```
<modules>
Module1
Module2
</modules>
```

`mvn dependency:tree` from the folder of `MyProject` is OK: module2 depends on module1

```
MyProject
---
com.acme:Module1:version
---
com.acme:Module2:version
+com.acme:Module1:version
```

The problem is if I run `mvn dependency:tree` inside the `Module2` folder.
I then get the error message:

```
The POM for com.acme:Module2:version is invalid, 
transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available
```

After a few investigations I have discovered that the *pom* file created/copied by the install part of the build as `m2/com/acme/myproject/Module1/version/Module1-version.pom` is the original *pom* file.
This one uses variables for versions as (duplicated in many other modules not listed here) or a system path (no choice to have a system dependency). These variables are defined in the parent POM file.
If I replace all the `${}` in the module *pom* file by their values then everything is fine.
Basically when building the whole thing, the values of the variables are available to all the dependent modules as this is the same process. When you build an individual module the variables defined in the parent POM are not available.

Your own framework pom file contains a variable for the systempath of `net.sf.javaml`.
Hardcode the variable or find another solution like a bill of material.
https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html

Comment: Do you have any variable in the failing POM file where the variable is not defined in the same POM file? If yes, this can be the issue.

Comment: No, I took out the variables and nothing changed. Mysteriously this problem disappeared for some other reason and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that the client and server projects poms are invalid because of unsatisfied  expansion, then the following should work... If the "client" and "server" projects have their dependency on "Framework" defined in a  tag, then you can first install "Framework" using the -N option.  First, cd to the Framework directory, then:
`mvn -N clean install`
The -N option tells maven to only install the root pom in the local repo and to skip the child modules.  Now cd to your child project and rerun your install command in your client or server module.  The client or server build should now find the parent pom with the properties that it needs in the local repo.

You can get the same effect by making an explicit file path reference using the relativePath tag in your child pom's parent tag:

```
<parent>
  <relativePath>../my-parent</relativePath>
</parent>
```

Answer (score 2):

The the *Framework* artifact available in your local repository before running an `install` on the *client* project because there is no coupling between the two projects (the *client* artifact is not a `module` of your *Framework* project).

So to solve the issue you should run `mvn install` on your *Framework* project so the packaged jar is copied to your local repository. Then it is up to maven to discover and find it when you run some maven phase on the *client* project.

To have your artifacts shared among your organization you should deploy your artifacts (upload) to a nexus hosting mirror.

Comment: Noep, sorry. THis doesn't do anything. As I said, Framework is installed in the local repository and my Client project can see all the Framework native code. It just can't access the libraries that are dependancies of Framework.

Comment: Which scope do the Framework project dependencies have?

Comment: Most fo them are the default scope and one local jar is scope "system"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I am managing all the modules that were referenced by the project that i was trying to build. And the problem turned out that i had to do "mvn deploy" on all the parent projects of the module that was showing this error when using in another modules pom.xml. Here is the whole explanation http://programtalk.com/java/i-used-to-get-this-maven-error-all-time/

Answer (score 0):

You must to send output to log file with this command:

mvn clean install --log-file C:\XXXX\Maven\log.txt

open log.txt and analize what dependencies are not found or pom.xml are in not valid state

remove pom's that are not valid and re run mvn clean install

that is all.

Comment: what's the equivalent of this on mac? The logging out

Answer (score 0):

In my case maven corrupted one of transitive dependency pom (double content), so I just removed it in my m2 folder. -X key helped me to find the certain broken pom.

Answer (score 0):

For me the pom.xml contents load from a repository to the .m2 folder and the contents of the file when I opened was HTML content which was the reason why I was getting this WARNING message because the site was moved to a different repository location,

```
[WARNING] The POM for GROUPID:ARTIFACTID:PACKAGIN:VERSION is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
```

So I modified the pom.xml contents to,

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>GROUPID</groupId>
  <artifactId>ARTIFACTID</artifactId>
  <version>VERSION</version>
  <packaging>PACKAGIN</packaging>
</project>
```

Now if I run mvn clean install on the module which had the above dependency the warning din't show. So check the contents of the pom.xml.