# Getting "The POM for <name> is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available" only in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, jaxb, m2e

I have recently upgraded to JAXB 2.2.11 and noticed in my Eclipse console the following message:

```
10/15/14, 11:42:46 PM GMT+2: [INFO] Creating new launch configuration
10/15/14, 11:42:58 PM GMT+2: [INFO] C:\Projects\workspaces\mj2p\maven-jaxb2-plugin-project\tests\JAXB-1044
10/15/14, 11:42:58 PM GMT+2: [INFO]  mvn  -B -X -e clean install
10/16/14, 12:09:07 AM GMT+2: [WARN] The POM for com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.2.11 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available: 1 problem was encountered while building the effective model for com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.2.11
[ERROR] 'dependencyManagement.dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for com.sun:tools:jar must specify an absolute path but is ${tools.jar} @ 

10/16/14, 12:09:07 AM GMT+2: [WARN] The POM for com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-xjc:jar:2.2.11 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available: 1 problem was encountered while building the effective model for com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-xjc:2.2.11
[ERROR] 'dependencyManagement.dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for com.sun:tools:jar must specify an absolute path but is ${tools.jar} @ 

10/16/14, 12:09:07 AM GMT+2: [WARN] The POM for com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:jar:2.2.11 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available: 1 problem was encountered while building the effective model for com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:2.2.11
[ERROR] 'dependencyManagement.dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for com.sun:tools:jar must specify an absolute path but is ${tools.jar} @
```

What puzzles me is that I am not getting this warning in console. The `pom`s in question also seems to be correct. I am sure I am using the same Maven installation in the console and in Eclipse (`m2e`). The repository also seems to be correct.

Does anyone happen to know, what could be causing this?

> Please note that this is not a duplicate for (almost
>   identically-named) question:
>
> - [The POM for <name> is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23581194/the-pom-for-name-is-invalid-transitive-dependencies-if-any-will-not-be-avai)
>
> This question is about the differences between Maven execution in the console and from the Eclipse.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After further investigation it appears that I have the same problem as in this question:

> [Maven not picking JAVA_HOME correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13288735/maven-not-picking-java-home-correctly)

The [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23129154/303810) thanks to @rustyx (please upvote that answer):

> To fix the issue you need to start Eclipse using the JRE from the JDK by adding something like this to `eclipse.ini` (before `-vmargs`!):

```
-vm
C:\<your_path_to_jdk170>\jre\bin\javaw.exe
```

Answer (score 11):

The `pom` for `com.sun.xml.bind.jaxb-impl` has `com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-parent` has its parent.

`jaxb-parent pom` has the following section:

```
<profile>
    <id>default-tools.jar</id>
    <activation>
        <file>
            <exists>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</exists>
        </file>
    </activation>
    <properties>
        <tools.jar>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</tools.jar>
    </properties>
</profile>
<profile>
    <id>default-tools.jar-mac</id>
    <activation>
    <file>
        <exists>${java.home}/../Classes/classes.jar</exists>
    </file>
    </activation>
    <properties>
        <tools.jar>${java.home}/../Classes/classes.jar</tools.jar>
    </properties>
</profile>
```

In your Eclipse, neither of the profile seems to be activated due to which `${tools.jar}` does not have a value.

One possibility could be `JAVA_HOME` value is set incorrectly.

Comment: Just rechecked: `JAVA_HOME` is set correctly, the workspace is set up with a JDK. I'm not quite sure how to debug this.

Comment: Any chance `mvn:help-effective-pom` works and if so what output does it give?

Comment: Please see my other answer. This is an Eclipse bug (`java.home` is not being passed correctly by default).

Comment: in my case JAVA_HOME was not pointing to the bin directory but to its parent. Fixing this solved my problem

Comment: `JAVA_HOME` should point to the folder immediatly _above_ the `bin` folder . Then you add `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` to your `PATH` variable, or `$JAVA_HOME/bin`

Answer (score 2):

the pom for com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-osgi:jar:2.2.10 is invalid issue.
worked for me after updating the rest-assured version to 4.1.1.

Comment: I've upgraded to RestAssured 4.2.0 and it helped as well. I had some other problems with newer version, like 4.4.0.

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed out, this  might happen because the JRE is setup incorrectly within Eclipse.

I solved it by adding the correct entry (pointing to where mi JDK is installed) inside Window>Preferences>Java>Installed JRE's

After this change, a project clean might be necessary.

[image]