# Maven build war some classes not included

Tags: java, maven, compilation, war

When building maven webapp by using `mvn install` or `mvn compile war:war` on two different machines resulting WAR files have 20MB difference and their build times are 1 and a half minutes apart (30s vs 2min)

By inspecting war files using WinRAR I've noticed that smaller WAR does not contain WEB-INF\classes\WEB-INF and WEB-INF\classes\resource folders.

The whole codebase is the same. POM.xml contains `maven-compiler-plugin`, webapp and unit tests run well on both apps with difference that smaller WAR seems to not have included properties files for language locality.

Comment: Please stick to consistently using `mvn clean install` or `mvn clean package` (which does not install the WAR in your local repo). Using `mvn compile war:war` is very different and will not build your WAR file correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely one of the machines stores corrupted artifacts in the local maven repository or points to a mirror server with broken artifacts. When artifact has invalid `pom.xml` or parent's `pom.xml` can't be resolved you will get a warning:

> The POM for  is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available

Inspect the console output and confirm there are no such warnings. See [this answer for further reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23581194/the-pom-for-name-is-invalid-transitive-dependencies-if-any-will-not-be-avai).

It also could be Maven version used differs on both machines. This could result in Maven War Plugin running in different versions, one of them could be affected by a bug. Ensure that both builds use the same Maven version and configuration e.g. with [Maven Wrapper](https://github.com/takari/maven-wrapper).

There is also a chance that you have a non standard build with modules being bound manually to phases e.g. Maven Assembly Plugin bound to `test` phase. Ensure that both machines build the artifact with exactly the same command.

Above generally illustrates why one should have a CI server to get reproducible builds.

Comment: Both console outputs are the same. What could I do about broken artifacts?

Comment: @Cirko ensure that there are no warnings during build in console output.

Comment: No warnings, the console outputs are the same. I've checked them side by side.

Comment: Compare `mvn -X install` output. It's very verbose so use `diff`. Look for output from maven war plugin and compare all plugin executions ids.

Comment: I've deleted .m2 folder and let the project build maven dependencies again and that solved the problem! Thanks!

Comment: I strongly recommend to turn on checksum policy https://blog.soebes.de/blog/2018/10/13/maven-artifact-checksums-what/

Answer (score 0):

The differences between the two machines may be the maven settings located in ~/.m2/settings.xml

consider adding a maven wrapper to your project 
@see : https://www.baeldung.com/maven-wrapper

Comment: Simply no...and the wrapper will not help to solve a possible existing difference in s`settings.xml`...