# Intellij can't resolve transitive dependencies

Tags: java, macos, maven, intellij-idea, java-8

I have weird issue, `mvn clean install -Dproject.version=1` or `jenkins` build is going through fine but intellij is all red and angry when i open the modules in IDE, this affects the development.

I see below issue in intellij logs

> The POM for << module >> is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any)
>   will not be available, enable debug logging for more details

Code is heavily copyrighted so cant disclose but here is a basic outline

- fabric-common : base module (*common fabric to bind entire project* , contains all clients and db modules ) - lets call it `FC`
- utilities : module in question ( `import`s `FC` ) and uses db modules        - lets call utilities  `U`

Now `U` is all red because it cant find DAO's of db, if `U`s POM explicitly contains `db` modules every one is happy.

`Auto-Import` on intellij is enabled, imports are happening on `maven3`, and local repository is all updated with correct version too.

Is this a [known issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-98503) or any help around?

Intellij details

[image]

### Edit

Question suggested [as duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23581194/the-pom-for-name-is-invalid-transitive-dependencies-if-any-will-not-be-avai) is an issue specific to `maven` not able to resolve dependencies but in my case, `maven` build from command line or jenkins is fine but IDE fails.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The POM for <name> is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23581194/the-pom-for-name-is-invalid-transitive-dependencies-if-any-will-not-be-avai)

Comment: nope...that thread is about an issue with `maven` itself, in my case, `intellij` is crying, `maven` is cool!

Comment: Try running maven clean install from inside IntelliJ

Comment: @chaitan64arun as in the `terminal` of `intellij`..right? or some other place in IDE? if terminal of intellij, then done already, no help in removing red highlights from IDE!!!

Comment: No from "Maven build" which is generally on the right side. You get it by installing "Maven Integration" plugin

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/img/idea/2019.1/maven_tool_window_structure.png

Comment: @chaitan64arun : hmmm...never tried this. how do i pass `project.version` in this? seems to just run `install` command on click which fails due to missing version!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try to

- invalidate cache an restart
- delete `.iml` and `.ipr` files
- clean up `Project structure` (if I recall correctly) Libraries or Artifacts. Just delete them, so they get updated via Maven.
- run mvn `idea:idea`

in arbitrary order. I cannot recall which one it was, but I'd place my bets on `.ipr`/`.iml`, clean up `Project structure` and `Invalidate restart`

### Edit

here is what worked

---

ensure intellij is open before we start doing this ( needed to invalidate cache in step 3 ) and you have setup `maven3` as home directory ( `Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deploymnet -> Maven : Maven Home directory`)

delete all iml, ipr, iws

```
cd <parent dir of project>
find project/ -type f -name "*iml*" -exec rm {} \;
find project/ -type f -name "*ipr*" -exec rm {} \;
find project/ -type f -name "*iws*" -exec rm {} \;
```

remove local repository

```
   cd ~/.m2
   mv repository* ~/Desktop/
```

:: close the intellij project window ( not intellij, just project window )

:: invalidate cache and restart ( this would close intellij and restart with blank screen)

:: once intellij opens, open the project by selecting project level POM ( this would re-import all dependencies in local again -  one we deleted in step 4 )

```
cd < project path >
```

:: run ( in intellij terminal if possible - being superstitious here   )  - this would update local intellij:

```
mvn -U idea:idea -Dproject.version=1.0
```

:: right click on pom.xml of specific project, `Maven -> Reimport`