# Maven surefire shows an error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject

Tags: java, maven, testing, automated-tests, apache-poi

Everywhere it says that the error is due to the lack of *xmlbeans*, but it is indicated in my dependencies.

```
[ERROR] script3(script_1_2_3.TestScripts)  Time elapsed: 33.818 s  <<< ERROR!
java.io.IOException: org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlException
       at script_1_2_3.TestScripts.script3(TestScripts.java:84)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlException
       at script_1_2_3.TestScripts.script3(TestScripts.java:84)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException
       at script_1_2_3.TestScripts.script3(TestScripts.java:84)
```

Here is a complete list of these apache.poi dependencies from the POM file.

```
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>

            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>

            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>

            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>

            <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>

            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
```

Also, before starting the tests, warning messages appear that apply to all poi packages, but the tests run.

```
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.poi: poi:jar:4.1.0 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.poi: poi-ooxml:jar:4.1.0 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.poi: poi-ooxml-schemas:jar:4.1.0 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:jar:3.1.0 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.poi: poi-scratchpad:jar:3.9 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.poi: openxml4j:jar:1.0-beta is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23581194/the-pom-for-name-is-invalid-transitive-dependencies-if-any-will-not-be-avai suggests a general strategy to identify the bad POM using `mvn dependency:tree -X`. I disagree with the answer there to use `mvn install -N` that is _a_ solution but may not be the correct solution for you.

Comment: In addition the "enable debug logging" part of the message is important. You can set that for any `mvn`  call by passing the `-X` flag for any operation. The warning is telling you how to get more details, please capture those details and update your post.